# How to pass raw json data in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am implementing following web api in Retrofit.
[api example in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMHq.png)

To call the api I have implemented three classes.

**api.java**

```
public interface Api {
    @POST("/login.jsp")
    void login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest, Callback<String> callback);
}
```

**LoginRequest.java**

```
public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**ServiceClient.java**

```
public class ServiceClient {
    private static Api api;
    private static String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/xxx";

    static {
        setupServiceClient();
    }

    private ServiceClient() {}

    public static Api get() {
        return api;
    }

    private static void setupServiceClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to call the api as following.

```
ServiceClient.get().login(new LoginRequest(user, password), new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                Log.i(TAG, "SUCESS");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ERROR");
            }
        });
```

But unfortunately the app crashes after calling the api. I am suspecting the issue is involved in raw json parameter value.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please post the stacktrace from your logcat?

Comment: add `.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)` to `Retrofit.Builder` and then post log from logcat

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I was also facing problem in implementing login using Retrofit.

Comment: I was able to detect the issue was on output value from web api by checking logs. In my case, the log in api returns just status code with empty string value. Thus, Retrofit was confusing to convert empty string value to GSON. I have sent a request to modify the web api to server guy. I will see how it will be going. I will post here a result.

Comment: The login api has been changed to return NULL with status code. Other apis return JSON values. But I am getting following error message via the login api. "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $" Any advice?

Comment: I could catch up header type at logs. The issue occurred due to the header type of HTTP/TEXT. When I have changed it to Application/JSON, the issue has gone.